# Unable compile my app with Secured channel in my J2ME Emulator

Tags: netbeans, java-me, lwuit

In my lwuit project I use secured channel, since I use secured channel my j2me emulator open my app which connects with secured channel and throws an error stating `Sorry. Your phone does not have appropriate certificate to make connection with the server.`

How can I compile with secured channel in my j2me emulator is there any way out to solve this problem?

Comment: did you check the emulator documentation? User guide etc. If memory serves WTK / Java ME SDK docs have dedicated sections describing how to get certificates for testing purposes

Answer (score 1):

Some newer certificates just aren't available on old phones. E.g. facebook/twitter use new certificates that aren't available on older devices.